# Suppose $p$ and $q$ are odd primes and $p = q + 4a$ for some $a$. Prove that $(\frac ap) = (\frac aq)$ holds.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

This problem also had me prove that $(\frac pq) = (\frac aq)$, but I've already managed to do that. I've tried messing around with the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity but can't get anything. I've also tried using the first identity by proving that $(\frac pq) = (\frac ap)$, but again I've got nothing.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, this version seems to have an easier proof.

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close.  Yes, this question is a *corollary* of the other question, but it's a special case, not a duplicate -- and in this case it's a special case with a simpler proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=q+4a$, then $p\equiv q$ mod $4$, in which case the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity says

$$\left({p\over q}\right)=\left({-q\over p}\right)$$
But this gives

$$\left({a\over q}\right)=\left({q+4a\over q}\right)=\left({p\over q}\right)=\left({-q\over p}\right)=\left({4a-p\over p}\right)=\left({a\over p}\right)$$

(using the fact that $4$ is a square, hence a quadratic residue for both $p$ and $q$).

Comment: But $(\dfrac {p}{q}) = (\dfrac {-q}{p})$ only if $p \equiv q \equiv 3 \space (mod \space 4).$ If $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \space (mod \space 4)$ then $(\dfrac {p}{q}) = (\dfrac {q}{p})$.

Comment: @clocks, if $p\equiv q\equiv1$ mod $4$, then $({-1\over p})=({-1\over q})=1$, so the equality I asserted holds in both cases.