# Elementary Application of Legendre Symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For odd primes $p,q$ with $p\equiv q\pmod{4a}$, then how can we show that $a$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$ if and only if it is a quadratic residue $\mod q$ using legendre/jacobi symbols?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609560/suppose-p-and-q-are-odd-primes-and-p-q-4a-for-some-a-prove-that